# Pandas dataframe - how to connect patients by outcome label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry, not sure how to word this. I have a large database of multiple patients, and I want to create a new dataframe in which the patients are connected by a shared outcome (0 or 1). I guess something that would turn a dataframe like this:

| ID | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |

Into this:

| ID 1 | ID 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

out = (df.groupby('Outcome', group_keys=False, sort=False)['ID']
         .apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(combinations(g, 2)))
         .set_axis(['ID1', 'ID2'], axis=1)
      )
```

Alternative with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(combinations(v, 2), columns=['ID1', 'ID2'])
                 for k, v in df.groupby('Outcome', group_keys=False,
                                        sort=False)['ID']
                ], ignore_index=True
```

Output:

```
   ID1  ID2
0    1    3
1    1    4
2    3    4
0    2    5
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have enough RAM to run this though as I keep getting crashes. Is there a way to do this for a large (30,000+) amount of data?

Comment: @user17753 well, combinations of 30k items by pairs gives about 450M possibilities, that's a lot, are you sure you need to get all?

Comment: I'm creating a graph neural network following this tutorial (https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gnn-an-end-to-end-guide-for-graph-neural-networks-a66bfd237c8c) and need to use it for the edge data (source/target).

Comment: You don't need to create all edges, no? Another option is to use the outcome as node. Depends what you want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm doing a node prediction task, so I'm trying to predict the outcome for the patient. The node data includes a lot of information/diagnostics about the patient. I'm unsure what the source/target in the edge data is in this context. I thought that it would be two patients that share the same outcome, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should probably leave this question as it is as it might be useful to others in its current state, and open a new one with all details of the node prediction task.